# What is the difference between a modifiable rvalue and a const rvalue?

Tags: c++, rvalue

```
string three() { return "kittens"; }

const string four() { return "are an essential part of a healthy diet"; }
```

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c0x-features-in-vc10-part-2/) article, the first line is a modifiable rvalue while the second is a const rvalue. Can anyone explain what this means?

Comment: Obviously because kittens grow up and become cats.

Comment: With the first you can do e.g. `three()[0] = 'K'`, you can't do something like that with the second function.

Comment: the names already say all. One is const the other isnt.

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, but what what is happening inside of the compiler when those are called?

Comment: The compiler is stopping you from doing non-const things to const-qualified (rvalue or other) references. This is exactly the same as every other const-qualified type, and the linked article says as much. Are you really asking what const does in general?

Comment: @Useless the real question I am trying to figure out here is such: why does, for example, int myFunction(const int& myInput) take any value while int myFunction(int& myInput) only take modifiable lvalues? How is it possible that you could "reference" the address of an rvalue using const int&?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return values of your function are copied using std::string's copy constructor. You can see that if you step through your program execution with a debugger.

As the conments say, it's quite self explantory.  The first value will be editable when you return it. The second value will be read-only. It is a constant value.

For example:

```
int main() {


   std::cout << three().insert(0, "All ")  << std::endl; // Output: All kittens.

   std::cout << four().insert(0, "women ") << std::endl; // Output: This does not compile as four() returns a const std::string value. You would expect the output to be "women are an essential part of a healthy diet”. This will work if you remove the const preceding the four function.

}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `four().begin(), four.end()`? That would be iterators to different `std::string`, right?

Comment: @Zereges. Ammended.

Answer (score -2):

An **rvalue** is the one which can be written at the write side of an assignment operator. A **Modifiable Rvalue** is the one (as it is visible from name) whose value can be changed at any time during execution. While, on the other hand, **const Rvalue** is a constant which cannot be changed during Program execution.