# Why can I assign value to rvalue reference which refers to literals?

Tags: c++

Why assigning value to a rvalue reference (which refers to literals) is allowed?

```
int main()
{
    int&& a = 5;
    cout << a << endl;  //5
    a = 6;
    cout << a << endl;  //6
}
```

---

Here's how I understand things:

- Literals like `"string"`,`12`, can never be changed. They are something "objective".
- I can use variable to copy these literal values, store them, change them, for which I am actually changing the copies in the variables. E.g. An ordinary variable initialization `int a = 3; a = 4;`
- Some kinds of rvalue can be changed. I know there are *modifable rvalue* and *const rvalue*. E.g. [What is the difference between a modifiable rvalue and a const rvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019243/what-is-the-difference-between-a-modifiable-rvalue-and-a-const-rvalue) .

E.g. I can change a temporary object returned by a function, which is a rvalue.

```
string three() { return “kittens”; }
three().insert(0, "All ")
```

But here I understand that it's changing a temporary variable returned by function `three()`, not changing the literals `"kittens"`.

So I am confused about the sample in the beginning, why am I allowed to change a *rvalue reference*, which refers to number `5`? What's going on when I assgin `a = 6;`?

Comment: `int&& a = 5;` create a temporary.

Comment: @Jarod42 , never heard of it. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085796/what-happens-when-you-assign-a-literal-constant-to-an-rvalue-reference

Comment: Anything with a name is not an rvalue. So `int&& a = 5;` does not create an rvalue.

Comment: Rvalue reference variables are lvalues when used in expressions.